# How to add a views block in a basic page via editor?

Tags: 7, nodes

I have created a basic page through the editor of drupal 7 and I have started coding the body using the PHP code text format. So far so good, apart from the fact that I want to embed a block from a view (showing three nodes) and the code below which seems to work when I put it directly into a php file, doesn't activate within the body. I am using Bootstrap by the way.

```
<div class="third-box">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <?php print views_embed_view("mylatest_events", "block"); ?>
  </div>

  <div class=clear></div>
  <p class="text-center"><br><strong>Flavour text to describe the view here.</strong></p>
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the simplest php-code inside your body field ?
For example,

```
<?php print 'The simplest text'; ?>
```

It can be situation, where filter for content of your field is configured wrongly.

Moreover, it would be nice to try names of the view and view mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way...

```
<?php
$block = block_load('views', 'your_block_name'); 
print render(_block_get_renderable_array(_block_render_blocks(array($block))));
?>
```